# Правильный редирект на HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, http, редирект, https, протоколы

Подключил протокол HTTPS, теперь делаю редирект с HTTP на HTTPS, код в htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydomain.net/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Переход происходит неправильно, т.е. при открытии главной страницы сайта, с HTTP происходит редирект на HTTPS, но при переходе на определенную страницу сайта, типа: mydomain.net/page/1 происходит редирект на главную страницу сайта с протоколом HTTPS.

Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Советую отличную статью по покупке и настройке https на nginx <a href="https://onlinebd.ru/blog/instrukciya-po-nastroike-https-dlya-php-fpm-s-ocenkoi-a">Полная инструкция по настройке HTTPS с оценкой А+</a>

Comment: Ошибка :с
Видно что-то не так. <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

Comment: А что это а кусочек кода? С ним что-то не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно так:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

А [здесь](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS) можно найти подробности.

Comment: Происходит циклическая переадресация, и браузер не открывает сайт

Comment: Приведённый мною код взят из официального руководства с apache.org, он гарантированно рабочий. У Вас или что-то ещё написано в `.htaccess`, или закешировался редирект в клиенте, или редиректит сама HTML страница, или ещё что-нибудь в таком духе.

Comment: Это для .htaccess или site.conf ?

Comment: по ссылке в моём ответе видно, что это пример для `.htaccess`

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

По идее как-то так

Comment: так неправильно.